# Cisco RV110W: Use LAN port as WAN?

Tags: cisco, wifi

I have Cisco RV110W Wireless router. WAN port was burned after a storm. Can I use one of LAN ports as WAN?

Looking under "Switch Settings" I can't find solution. In the Cisco [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv110w/administration/guide/rv110w_admin.pdf), I could not find a solution either.

Comment: It may no longer work as a router. But it might still work as an access point. Many wireless routers can be used as access point if you simply disable the DHCP server and then leave the WAN port disconnected.

Comment: (put scotch tape over the WAN port)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope.

The [Cisco RV110W](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/rv110w-wireless-n-vpn-firewall/index.html) device you have contains a [dedicated WAN port](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/routers/small-business-rv-series-routers/cisco_rv110w_ov_0425.pdf). This is a physical hardware port intended for this purpose. You will not be able to reassign WAN functions to one of the four switch ports.

[image]

More importantly, [equipment damaged in an electrical storm](https://serverfault.com/questions/408130/assessing-equipment-damage-following-a-lightning-strike-should-i-have-planned) really should not be trusted. You're going to have to replace this router.

Comment: I never type quick enough lol...but your answer has a picture...so +1 :)

Comment: Just to illustrate the separation... Versus something like a Cisco ASA 5505, whose ports *can* be reconfigured.

Comment: And +1 from me for linking to our canonical lightning-strike-mitigation question - smoooothly done!

Comment: I guess, too bad( Thx for reply

Comment: Well, technically, all five ports are on a single switch, and it has the WAN port on a separate VLAN (VLAN 1, untagged), which is why it's reserved. And of course the firmware does not let you reassign the port to another VLAN. Third party firmware might allow it though.

Comment: But... Storm damage.

Answer (score 2):

I believe DD-WRT will  this, e.g. to set up the other LAN ports under separate, NATted subnets, and other neat tricks.  DD-WRT is a complete firmware replacement, that installs a very small version of Linux, and the tools necessary to manage it. You can find it at dd-wrt.org, with probably a better explanation, instructions, and so forth.

dd-wrt is probably a 4 out of 5 on a technical scale to get installed, but if you find this intriguing, i might be worth it at least to try since it's not a router otherwise.

this forum indicates the hardware is the same is a Cisco E2000, so that image is known to work:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=141699&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15&sid=8056260fc95a2b055afde005b32eee7d

01/06/15 edited for grammar/clarity

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this in a professional environment... but it's a good idea for home use/small offices.

Comment: I'd much sooner use OpenWrt, as DD-WRT's future is questionable, but the general advice is sound.

Comment: good idea, i try this, thx