# HP DL380 G7 Will Not Power On

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

We have a similiar issue to a few other people on here, although nothing we have tried has led us to a solution. We have an HP Proliant **DL380 G7** that will not power on (most of the time). Here's what we've seen happen with it:

- After a power down (usually power failure), power light stays Amber when pressed, no fans or any action. PSU fans are on, no lights on PSU.
- Power button is pressed, server powers on, performs normally. (has only happened once or twice, stroke of luck?)
- Power button is pressed, server powered on, but very quietly. Normally sounds like a hurricane on startup. Took awhile to POST, but never initializes hard drives. They never power on, so server cannot boot.

Here's where it gets interesting. After the last bullet happened, we turned the server off, then on again. Upon turning the server back on:

- Power light turns green
- Hard Drive lights all Flash like they are being checked.
- Server power cycles after ~1-2 seconds.
- Rinse and repeat

That last case has happened twice, most recently. We've tried flipping the System Maintenance DIP switches 6, and 1,5,6 with no luck. When we try this method, we cannot get the server to turn on (stuck on an Amber light).

We tried minimizing the configuration, down to only CPU (no PCI bus, no HDD controller, no/minimal RAM). We also bought two new power supplies, which appear to make no difference. We have tried new and old power supplies in it, only one, several configurations. These problems started after a power outage.

Answer (score 3):

I have an HP ProLiant DL380 G7 unit sitting here with this issue.

**[See the video.](https://www.instagram.com/p/BPIRabKjdrI/?taken-by=ewwhite)**

The power switch and/or connection to the system board is bad. This is a replaceable part, and the system board is not necessarily the issue.

I was able to get this system to boot by massaging the connector from the from SID panel (power switch) to the motherboard. Try pulling it out and gently inserting it while holding the power button.

The unit here was damaged during a series of [power surges and lightning strikes](https://serverfault.com/q/408130/13325) in a sub-optimal operating environment.

You could call this in to HP for out-of-warranty repair or replace the affected components or pick up a spare DL380 G7 chassis ($250) and go from there. If you're in the US, a spare chassis is the easiest.

Comment: Tried your suggestion with no results.

Comment: @Rudedog9d I gave several suggestions. First, is the video I posted consistent with your symptoms? If so, it IS possible to jump-start the server. But you know that the problem is power switch related. Please try powering on, then immediately unplugging the motherboard connector. See if things stay on.

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, and more. No amount of fiddling with the power switch/cord produced any results, unfortunately. Also, the video was not exactly the same as my problem. Thanks for the effort though! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your motherboard seem to be in trouble. This is the only part you didn't tested.

I would check for a spare ML380G7 on ebay to borrow those part on it if you really need time to migrate the data.

I seen a server that did symptom like your and it finished as a new server. (as it was out of warranty)

Comment: That's the sad realization I am coming to. Motherboards are cheap though!